# Search Bar and Fractional Sizes

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, advanced-search

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

In the store I manage, many products are differentiated by fractional sizes.  We sell 1/2", 5/8", 3/4", etc.

When customers search these terms in the search bar, the searches are processed in ASCII.  What ultimately happens is that we get a lot of searches for half inch items that come in as...

- 1%2F2
- 1&#472
- 1%2F2&#34
- 1&#472&#34

And so on.

What are some Magento best practices on this?
How can I better optimize the store to deliver more relevant search results?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Magento search result produced sometimes irrelevant if not configured correctly. i can suggest you check out your attributes. Look into **"Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes"** inside magento and you can try to turn off other searchable attributes that you don't need so that the list becomes smaller and more accurate.

another suggestion is under magento admin **System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search** where you can set up the Minimal Query Length, Maximum Query Length, Maximum Query Word Count and et.

Last suggestion is use this extension. i have used it before and work for me. i have tested it with magento 1.8.1

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog-search-refinement-free.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: It certainly does.  Sorry for the delay in responding.  Everyone should up-vote your answer.